# keyboardWillHide notification malfunction

Tags: ios, swift

I have:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}
```

And also:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if (self.view.center.y == maxPointY){
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= maxPointY/2
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    self.view.frame.origin.y += maxPointY/2
}
```

The problem is that when I click on a textfield that should pop up the keyboard, `keyboardWillHide` gets called.

I have this as well:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    usernameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Did you added any resign code in textField delegate methods?Call  keyboardWillShow with self keyword or class.

Comment: There is no such line of code above that suggests that "when I click on a textfield that should pop up the keyboard"

Comment: check it out Change UIKeyboardWillShow observer to UIKeyboardDidShow.Comment keyboardWillHide func.

Answer (score 1):

Try this  : **Swift 3**

It is working in my side . I think you have passed selector without arguments

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

**Selector**

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    }

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
     }
```

**Delegate**

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
```

Comment: No, none of these worked. I have 2 text fields, if that matters. Please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

It was this tidbit:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

I didn't call `super.touchesBegan`. I had to change it to:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
self.view.endEditing(true)
super.touchesBegan(touches , with:event)
}
```